# Laravel components for livewire doesn't show validation errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

So I have been trying to make a component for every input and form component I use in my project so I put every select2, input, ckeditor etc... to a anonymous component and my problem is the validation errors doesn't show up.

**My Select2 Component:**

```
@props([
    'id' => 'ckeditor',
    'ref' => 'ckeditor',
    'name' => 'description',
    'label' => 'CKEditor'
])
<div wire:ignore class="form-group @error($name) is-invalid @enderror">
    <div class="{{ $attributes->get('class') ?? 'col-md-12' }}">
        <label class="form-label" for="{{ $id }}">{{ $label }}</label>
        <textarea wire:model.defer="{{ $attributes->whereStartsWith('wire:model')->first() }}" class="form-control ckeditor"
                  name="{{ $name }}"
                  id="{{ $id }}">
        </textarea>
        @error($name)
        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        $("document").ready(function () {
            ClassicEditor
                .create(document.querySelector('#{{ $id }}'), {
                    toolbar: [
                        "heading", "|",
                        'bold', 'italic', '|',
                        "link", '|',
                        'bulletedList', 'numberedList', '|',
                        'blockQuote', '|',
                        'outdent', 'indent', '|',
                        'undo', 'redo', '|',
                    ],
                })
                .then(editor => {
                    editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
                    @this.set('{{ $attributes->whereStartsWith('wire:model')->first() }}', editor.getData());
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        })
    </script>
@endpush
```

**My CKEditor Component:**

```
@props([
    'id' => 'ckeditor',
    'ref' => 'ckeditor',
    'name' => 'description',
    'label' => 'CKEditor'
])
<div wire:ignore class="form-group @error($name) is-invalid @enderror">
    <div class="{{ $attributes->get('class') ?? 'col-md-12' }}">
        <label class="form-label" for="{{ $id }}">{{ $label }}</label>
        <textarea wire:model.defer="{{ $attributes->whereStartsWith('wire:model')->first() }}" class="form-control ckeditor"
                  name="{{ $name }}"
                  id="{{ $id }}">
        </textarea>
        @error($name)
        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        $("document").ready(function () {
            ClassicEditor
                .create(document.querySelector('#{{ $id }}'), {
                    toolbar: [
                        "heading", "|",
                        'bold', 'italic', '|',
                        "link", '|',
                        'bulletedList', 'numberedList', '|',
                        'blockQuote', '|',
                        'outdent', 'indent', '|',
                        'undo', 'redo', '|',
                    ],
                })
                .then(editor => {
                    editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
                    @this.set('{{ $attributes->whereStartsWith('wire:model')->first() }}', editor.getData());
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        })
    </script>
@endpush
```

I don't know why the error doesn't show even though I have the @error and its more likely correct.
Any Ideas and help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: instead @error($name) try @error('{{$name}}')

Comment: my answer was totally wrong...the thing with it is the wire:ignore directive. Try instead use wire:ignore.self or move the @error directive out of that container